# How to prevent Django caching querysets in memory in a ./manage.py command

Tags: python, django

I have a ./manage.py command that is made to run as a service in the background. However the memory usage goes up steadily and the script gets killed eventually. By using [memory_profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) I found that the memory usage goes up after each query, especially after `bulk_create()`.

I tried putting the results in a variable and setting it to `None`, also tried `django.db.connection.close()` after each iteration of the endless loop.

Is there a way to tell Django not to cache those queries? These are the problematic queries:

```py
A = Item.objects.filter(A_query_filter).order_by('-added')
Item.objects.filter(D_query_filter).delete()
Item.objects.bulk_create(C, ignore_conflicts=True, batch_size=1000)
Unique.objects.bulk_create(F, ignore_conflicts=True, batch_size=1000)
deleted = Player.objects.filter(G_query_filter).delete()
Player.objects.bulk_create(G, batch_size=1000)
```

This is a screenshot of what memory_profiler tells me while the script is running. On the third column you can see the memory consumed increasing after each query.

[image]

Comment: You should use `batch_size` parameter during performing bulk creates. Also you should look in [`iterator()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) method for queryset which will read results directly, without doing any caching at the QuerySet level

Comment: @MahenderThakur I'm already doing that. The problem is that the memory used goes up steadily after each call of bulk create.

Comment: For django not to cache those queries and if you are using objects only once , you should use `iterator()` method as i mentioned above as it will allow you to optimize the memory usage . Also please share some snippets , because we can not find or debug solution without seeing the problem

Comment: I added the queries I'm making. The rest of the script is just manipulating sets and dictionaries.

Comment: Also attached a screenshot of the memory_profiler output.